# Can someone help me understand ALG and VPN settings on my router?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, router

I'm looking at the settings in my TP-LINK WDR4300 router and noticed settings for VPN passthrough and ALG. Every single option is enabled but I am hoping someone can help me understand these settings and what they do and whether or not I should leave them enabled. I am pretty sure none of this applies to me.

Thanks in advance in case I am not able to finish the account sign up on this site. I asked a question a few weeks ago but my email never responded and I was not able to respond to the helpful people.

> VPN - VPN Passthrough must be enabled if you want to allow VPN tunnels
>   using VPN protocols to pass through the Router.
>
> PPTP Passthrough - PPTP Passthrough. Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol
>   (PPTP) allows the Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) to be tunneled through
>   an IP network. To allow PPTP tunnels to pass through the Router, click
>   Enable.
>
> L2TP Passthrough - Layer Two Tunneling Protocol (L2TP) is the method
>   used to enable Point-to-Point sessions via the Internet on the Layer
>   Two level. To allow L2TP tunnels to pass through the Router, click
>   Enable.
>
> IPSec Passthrough - Internet Protocol security (IPSec) is a suite of
>   protocols for ensuring private, secure communications over Internet
>   Protocol (IP) networks, through the use of cryptographic security
>   services. To allow IPSec tunnels to pass through the Router, click
>   Enable.
>
> ALG - It is recommended to enable Application Layer Gateway (ALG)
>   because ALG allows customized Network Address Translation (NAT)
>   traversal filters to be plugged into the gateway to support address
>   and port translation for certain application layer "control/data"
>   protocols such as FTP, TFTP, H323 etc.
>
> FTP ALG - To allow FTP clients and servers to transfer data across
>   NAT, click Enable.
>
> TFTP ALG - To allow TFTP clients and servers to transfer data across
>   NAT, click Enable.
>
> H323 ALG - To allow Microsoft NetMeeting clients to communicate across
>   NAT, click Enable.
>
> RTSP ALG - To allow some media player clients to communicate with some
>   streaming media servers across NAT, click Enable.
>
> SIP ALG - To allow some multimedia clients to communicate across NAT,
>   click Enable.

Comment: There is a good explanation [here](https://superuser.com/a/1167690). In this day and age of everything being encrypted, I believe all of these may be left disabled.