# For better security, should I enable or disable these ALG firewall options - Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, firewall

I have DIR615 300M Router.  Hardware version E4.

It has a handful of options to configure under Firewall settings. I am particularly interested in ALG settings. What exactly is this ALG and for better security (in case any),  should I keep them enabled or disabled? What is recommended from better security point of view.
There's some info under Help but I could not get much idea from it. This is what it says.

> Application Level Gateway (ALG) Configuration Here you can enable or
>   disable ALGs. Some protocols and applications require special handling
>   of the IP payload to make them work with network address translation
>   (NAT). Each ALG provides special handling for a specific protocol or
>   application. A number of ALGs for common applications are enabled by
>   default

As per comment to this question I did look into [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1167683/what-do-these-alg-setting-on-my-router-mean-and-what-is-alg?rq=1), however the security part if applicable is not covered in that thread. I am trying to understand if there's any relation to better security by either enabling or disabling these options.

Here's a screenshot of all settings.

[image]

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/1167683/what-do-these-alg-setting-on-my-router-mean-and-what-is-alg?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The sort answer is enable them only if you use the related services otherwise keep them unchecked... as mentioned on the comments for additional infos check [this QA](https://superuser.com/questions/1167683/what-do-these-alg-setting-on-my-router-mean-and-what-is-alg?rq=1)

Those ALG rules once enabled create exceptions on the firewall to allow the related network services (example: pptp vpn, or sip telephony), if the service is not used keep them unchecked for a better security.